# Unable to grab the same ID inside the form while edit action - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an Invoices app so that users can create the invoices.

The issue is when I create a **New Invoice** it's ID is **1** ( http://localhost:3000/invoices/1 ) as this is the first invoice that is **Invoice # 1** but when I go to **Edit** link it still shows ( http://localhost:3000/invoices/1/edit ) but with Invoice # 2, as it must grab the same ID i.e.,1 retaining **Invoice # 1**.

Here's an screenshot as below;

[image: screenshot.png]

_form.html.erb

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-4"><label>Invoice #</label></div>
    <div class="col-xs-8 invoice_num"><span id="invoice_number"><%= (Invoice.last.present? ? (Invoice.last.id + 1) : 1) %></span></div>
</div>
```

I don't know where I making the mistake.

Any suggestions are most welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what is the desired result?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Invoice # must be as per the id in the url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'r using default rails controller methods for `editing` and `creating` invoices you can use `@invoice` instance variable to access it's id when you want to edit an invoice:

```
<%= @invoice.id %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure that your links in your by your index action are getting the correct ID (i.e 1, 2, 3 rather than 1, 1, 1 etc)

Try this:

```
<% @invoices.each do |invoice| %>
  <%= link_to invoice %>
<% end %>
```